# Numerical Approximation - Finding roots

Tags: numerical-methods, factorial, numerical-calculus

Is someone able to assist me or atleast point me in the right direction of finding the roots of the below formula:

$$n^2−n+730\times\ln(0.5)=0$$

I have not done much numerical analysis/ approximation and am not sure how to go about this. If you are not willing to answer, please just point me in the right direction then.

I know what the roots should be, I am just not sure how to do this algebraically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason not to use the quadratic formula?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula with $a = 1, b = -1$ and $c = -730~\ln(2)$

Comment: OMW I feel like such an idiot. It is apart of a Numerical Analysis assignment so I completely blocked that aspect out. Thanks for making me feel dumb :D